# How to reclaim unused windows partition

Tags: 12.04, partitioning, windows

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 on a machine that previously have windows. On windows, there were three partition; 110GB, 190GB & 190GB.

I removed windows completely (my bad, only from) C drive and installed Ubuntu on C drive (110GB)

Now the problem is, only 100 GB is available for Ubuntu (10GB SWAP). Now I'm running out of space in /home directory and wanted to reclaim earlier D drive (190GB) in Ubuntu. Is there any way to do that or reinstalling Ubuntu from scratch is only option.

Below image show quick summary of partition:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First install `GParted Partition Editor` form Ubuntu software center.

Then format the partition to make it unallocated and make a new partition.

You can use more help from this [link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowtoPartition/ResizingPartition)

**NOTE :** You will need to boot from Live Media to re-size boot partition

Comment: You'll need to boot from Live media to resize your root partition

Comment: Why not make a separate partition instead of re-sizing. BTW thanks just mentioned it in answer

Comment: Because the OP wants to expand the root partition to have more space. Formatting the partition will delete all data on it